# Syntax errors while dividing integers

Tags: python, integer-division

Does anyone happen to see the error or errors that causing me to pull a syntax error?

```
#dividing integers
first = int (input('What is your first integer '))
second = int (input('What is your second integer '))

quotient = int (input('State the quotient of', str(first) , 'divided by', str(second))
print('you said the quotient  is ', quotient)
if  quotient== first / second:
    print('you are correct')
else:
    print('you are incorrect')
    print ( 'the quotient is ', first / second)
```

Comment: You are missing the final `)` on the end of the `quotient = int(input( ...`

Comment: Try to be more specific in your question. What exactly is the error saying?

Comment: Definitely not the `print()` statements.

Comment: `first / second` will always result in a float. And you are checking int value against float. You will never get the int value unless you convert it to int and check

Comment: I tried the code in my answer and I entered `100`, then `10` and then `10` and the program printed: `you are correct`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. One is the missing `)`. The other is that `input()` requires a single `str` parameter:

```py
#dividing integers
first = int (input('What is your first integer '))
second = int (input('What is your second integer '))

quotient = int (input('State the quotient of '+ str(first) + ' divided by ' + str(second)))
print('you said the quotient  is ', quotient)
if  quotient== first / second:
    print('you are correct')
else:
    print('you are incorrect')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help

Comment: I’ll upvote if you can improve your question with a full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with your code:

1. You are missing a `)` in the input statement for quotient. You
   need to fix that.
2. Your input statement is using commas. You should instead use + to concatenate the strings inside the input statement.

   'State the quotient of ' + str(first) + ' divided by ' + str(second)
3. Your code with the `if  quotient== first / second:` is checking an integer value with a float value.

For example, if the question was `State the quotient of 3 divided by 2` and the user answered `1`, your if statement will check as follows:

`if  1 == 3 / 2:`  This will be `if 1 == 1.5` which is never correct.

You need to convert the equation to

`if  quotient== first // second:` OR `if  quotient== int(first / second):`

Answer (score 0):

```
quotient = int (input('State the quotient of', str(first) , 'divided by', str(second))
```

1. Here you are missing ')' at the end
2. you are doing string concatenation incorrectly. Here is the correct one:

   quotient = int (input('State the quotient of ' + str(first) + ' divided by '+ str(second)))

Answer (score 0):

There were a few errors in your code. Here is one of the working approaches.

```
#dividing integers
first = input('What is your first integer ')
second = input('What is your second integer ')
    
quotient = input(f'State the quotient of {first} divided by {second}')
print('you said the quotient  is ', quotient)

if float(quotient) == int(first) / int(second):
    print('you are correct')
else:
    print('you are incorrect')
    print ( 'the quotient is ', int(first) / int(second))
```